# Sort from field other than Group Field in Crystal Reports

Tags: winforms, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2005

Using: VS2005; Crystal Report for VS2005; Oracle 9i; WinForms;

I have a report which displays the respective A/c Manager and their Revenue yield. The report is grouped by A/c Manager ID and have allowed drilled down feature on it. The Group is set to "On change of A/c Manager ID" hence I'm supposed to sort the result set with A/c Manager ID field, which I do and the it turns out to be perfect.

A/c Manager ID | Revenue
--------------   --------
1. A                 100
2. B                 200
3. C                  50

On a new requirement I'm supposed to change the sort order to Revenue field. However when Implemented, I see the Same A/c Manager scattered all over the place, which is obvious if you change the Sort other than Group Sorting field, which in this case is not A/c Manager ID.

A/c Manager ID | Revenue
--------------   --------
1. B                 200
2. A                 100
3. C                  50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the report menu, select group sort expert :)

Comment: Firstly Thanks! Your suggestion worked out. Thanks alot again!